# Trouble with being able to access a domain name pointing to my home IP address, but no on else

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, domain, virtual-machines

My situation:

Windows 7 64-bit host machine.
Ubuntu Server 10.04 running in VMWare
Using bridged networking instead of NAT and doing proper port forwarding for the VM
Nginx installed and configured as right as I can think to do on the VM
Behind a regular ol' d-link router but as aforementioned, forwarding ports correctly

My problem is that any domain, using GoDaddy for the nameserver and editing my DNS records to point A records at my home IP Address, ends up firing right up and working for me, but I can't get it working for external services I'm trying to build and have access it or just anyone I ask to take a look at it.

If I use one of those many networking tools sites online to access the DNS records, they report my the domains pointing to my IP address fine. At least one of the spare domains I've tried has been set to point to my IP address for over a month and I've been using it with IIS, so I don't think its a DNS issue.

But..for some reason everything is resolving for me but no one else and no apps I write on external servers that try and access it.

Note: I don't know much of anything about nginx or etc beyond the basics of the documentation, so assume I've not done anything other than stated above if you can help.

Thanks for any suggestions of what I might need to do, and note I'm just doing this for short-term, a few hours even development purposes, not trying to create anything for production, so if theres something I can do quickly to resolve this that isn't normally suggested for production I'd be fine doing that!

Comment: Are you certain your ISP allows incoming connections?  Are you able to access your system by IP?  You may need to just tell us the DNS name.

Comment: Woops. I looked up Cox's incoming port blocking and they do explicitly block port 80 for reason of web webservers. Sorry about overlooking this, 'least I can stop banging my head now thank you Zoredache.

Comment: You would have to make arrangements with your ISP to have a public IP assigned to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to a non-standard port for your testing and showing off things to others. Just append the port to the domain in the URL's you send out. eg http://mydomain.com:81

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Port switching works, but I think I'll talk to my ISP rather than circumvent 'less they say its more about filtering for protection than allowing this kind of testing.